# Python/Django creating several classes from variable through looping

Tags: python, django, class, view

I'm working with Python Django and I'm trying to create a forum with several subpages - each subpage concerns another topic and should look the same but store different posts. I want to create several classes (not instances!) with a similar name and same attributes. Each class should have another template name and render other posts. Something like this:

```
my_variable = 'part_of_class_name'

for class_number in range(2, 5):
    class_name = my_variable + str(class_number) + '(SameParentClass)'

    class class_name:
         template_name = 'template' + str(class_number) + '.html'
```

Of course, the code above doesn't work, is it a possibility to pass a variable to a class name? I want the following: part_of_class_name2(SameParentClass), part_of_class_name3(SameParentClass), part_of_class_name4(SameParentClass). How can I do it by looping? I want to avoid making three classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making three separate classes that do the same thing is not keeping with the [DRY philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Why not create a single class that takes a parameter, and use that parameter to get the specific behavior you want?

```
class ClassName:
    def __init__(self, class_number):
        self.template_name = 'test' + str(class_number) + '.html'


a = ClassName(1)
b = ClassName(2)
c = ClassName(3)

print(a.template_name)
print(b.template_name)
print(c.template_name)
```

Returns:

```
test1.html
test2.html
test3.html
```

Edit based on your comment - you can't call `as_view()` on an instance , but you can pass it a parameter that the class uses to set the template...something like this:

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ForumView

urlpatterns = [
    path('a', ForumView.as_view(template_name='a')),
    path('b', ForumView.as_view(template_name='b')),
    path('c', ForumView.as_view(template_name='c')),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from django.views.generic.base import View


class ForumView(View):
    template_name = None

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return TemplateResponse(request, self.template_name + '.html')
```

This would load `a.html` for a request to the `a` url, `b.html` for the `b` url, etc...

Comment: Looks good but now I'm struggling with urls.py, because a, b, c are class instances. How to pass it to URL without error? Usually I do the following: path('a/', views.a) or path('a/', views.a.as_view()) for CBV but it doesn't work with class instances and I haven't found any answer how to figure it out

Comment: @sebastian edited my answer, let me know if that helps

Comment: Yes, exactly. Very simple and clear solution, thanks a lot.